# Combined chart using AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to draw different domain data but varies with same parameter. Just like the below figure.
[image: Combined figure]

Does anyone can give me some hints using AChartEngine?

Comment: There is nothing to stop you displaying 2 separate charts in the same activity.

Comment: I know, but I want to scroll X axial simultaneously.